Kramer's degeneracy and ambiguity in time-reversal operator
To my understanding, time reversal symmetry can be represented by an anti-linear operator $T=U\mathcal{K}$, where $U$ is a unitary operator and $\mathcal{K}$ represents complex conjugation. This operator must satisfy, for spin$-\frac{1}{2}$ systems, the following properties
$$T^{-1}\vec{\sigma}T=-\vec{\sigma}.\\
T^{-1}\vec{r}T=\vec{r},\\
T^{-1}\vec{p}T=-\vec{p}.
$$
The usual choice $T=i\sigma^y\mathcal{K}$ fulfills these properties and satisfies $T^2=-1$, leading to the so-called Kramer's degeneracy.
My question is that, according to the aforementioned properties, the operator $T$ can also be defined as $T=\sigma^y\mathcal{K}$, since the operator $T$ only enters together with its inverse, leading to an ambiguity about the presence of the $i$ in the definition of $T$. However, if $T=\sigma^y\mathcal{K}$, this implies that $T^2=1$, and Kramer's degeneracy is no longer present. This means that an ambiguity in the definiton of an operator leads to a physical consequence, and this should not be the case. Is there any additional constraint on the definition of $T$ that fixes wheter there is or not an $i$ factor?

If $T=\sigma_y K$, then $T^2=\sigma_y K \sigma_y K = -\sigma_y^2 =-I$, no? Here, we employed the usual definition of $K$ in this context, which performs complex conjugation in the complete basis specified by the operators $r, \sigma_z$ (in particular the "standard representation" of the Pauli matrices were used, where $\sigma_y$ has purely imaginary entries).
